# Vertically center image in div while keeping Aspect Fit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a collection of very large size images (always larger than screen/browser window). My objective is to display image in full screen browser (like a picture frame, which are always horizontally and vertically centered in the div AND they are Aspect Fit in the Div.

I created a div like this:

```
<div id="main" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

Then I added an image in it like this:

```
if (photoWidth >= photoHeight) { // if this is a landscape or square image
    div.innerHTML = "<img style='flex:none;' height=" + screenHeight +  " src=images/" + encodeURI(imgName) + "></img>";
} else { // else if portrait image 
    div.innerHTML = "<img style='flex:none;'  width=" + screenWidth +  " src=images/" + encodeURI(imgName) + "></img>";
}
```

All work well for landscape or square images but if the image is portrait, it is not vertically centered in the div instead it it top aligned.

Comment: Give the image a percentage `max-width`, and make the height auto.

Comment: would be easier to make them background images then you could use background-size

Comment: FWIW, `<img>` is void element and does not have a closing tag `</img>`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: height is already auto since i have not specified it, tried max-width=100%, did not help

Comment: Use a `background-image` and `background-size: contain`? -- Why does the image have `flex: none`? Why are you concerned about the image being centrally aligned when the image is going to be bigger than the screen?

Comment: @hungerstar: removed </img> did not help.

Comment: @Kashif removing `</img>` is not supposed to fix the problem. Just informing you it's not needed.

Comment: I don't really understand what you have now. Is it like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWeXyB if not can you modify it so I can see what the current problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're going for but give it a try and let me know.

OP defined that portrait and landscape images can be cropped while square images should not be cropped.

### Portrait Example

Uses `background-size: cover;`, crops image.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('http://unsplash.it/2400/3200/?image=50');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Landscape Example

Uses `background-size: cover;`, crops image.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('http://unsplash.it/3200/2400/?image=100');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Square Example

Uses `background-size: contain;`, does not crop image.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('http://unsplash.it/3200/3200/?image=55');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: No, my portrait image is supposed to have the same width as screen but be centered vertically

Comment: You know that the top and/or bottom of the image will get cropped right? Or you allow it to take up a height greater than the viewport height. Those are your two choices with that requirement.

Comment: Yes, I expect top/bottom to be cropped

Comment: It is working great for landscape and portrait photos but if the photo is perfect square, it is trying to zoom into it, which I do not want.

Comment: So if it's a square you don't mind that it's not filling up it's container, i.e. whitespace?

Comment: yes, if it is square, I prefer it would not crop the image. whitespace is fine

Comment: Well, that's kind of an odd choice as you don't seem to care if cropping happens on portrait or landscape. In that case you will need to switch up the `background-size` property value to `contain` when the image is a square, [**Example JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zpwnpvco/).

Comment: EXCELLENT: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much!